# Значение по-умолчанию для выключенного GPS

Tags: java, android

Есть GPS данные которые отражаются в виде широты `56,1922` и долготы `37,8615`. Когда GPS приёмник выключен результат выводиться в виде `null` `null`. Есть желание сменить данный результат при выключеном приёмнике на `00,0000` `00,0000`, но что то не выходит побывал разные варианты всё остаётся так же.

При таком коде выводит   `null`    `null`

```
private void showLocation(Location location) {
    if (location == null)
        return;

    dataGPS1 = formatLocation1(location);
    dataGPS2 = formatLocation2(location);
}

public String formatLocation1(Location location) {// НА ВХОД БЕРЁТ Location location
    if (location == null)                         //ЧЕТАЕТ ИЗ НЕГО ДАННЫЕ И ВЫДАЁТ СТРОКУ
        return "";                                //ШИРОТА, ДОЛГОТА, ВРЕМЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ
    return String.format(
            "%1$.4f",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

}

public String formatLocation2(Location location) {// НА ВХОД БЕРЁТ Location location
    if (location == null)                         //ЧЕТАЕТ ИЗ НЕГО ДАННЫЕ И ВЫДАЁТ СТРОКУ
        return "";                                //ШИРОТА, ДОЛГОТА, ВРЕМЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ
    return String.format(
            "%2$.4f",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

}
```

Пытаюсь исправить тоже самое

```
private void showLocation(Location location) {
    if (formatLocation1(location).equals("null")){
        dataGPS1="00,0000"; ;
    }else{
        dataGPS1 = formatLocation1(location);
    }

    if (formatLocation2(location).equals("null")){
        dataGPS2="00,0000";
    }else{
        dataGPS2 = formatLocation2(location);
    }
}
```

Comment: `formatLocation1(location).equals("null")` точно невозможно, вы же сами проверяете `if (location == null) return ""`. Исправьте что-то из этого...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void showLocation(Location location) {
    if (location == null) {
        dataGPS1 = "00,0000";
        dataGPS2 = "00,0000";
        return;
    }

    dataGPS1 = formatLocation1(location);
    dataGPS2 = formatLocation2(location);
}
```

Comment: так тоже не работает

Comment: @VargSieg, Значит проблема не в этом участке кода. Как вы показываете текст?

Comment: ` file = new File(directory.getPath() + "/" + "  "
                         + dataGPS1 + "    " + dataGPS2 + "     " + ".jpg");`

Comment: @VargSieg, и что именно там не работает? Что нетак?

Comment: При выключенном GPS выводит в имя файла null null, а нужно 00,0000 00,0000

Comment: @VargSieg, может вы при выключенном GPS создаете файл до того, как вызвать showLocation?

Comment: Нет сначала запускается GPS жду когда будут результаты то есть когда значок перестанет мигать потом сохраняю и на выходе файл с координатами. При выключенном файл с null null

Comment: @VargSieg,  ну вы дебаггером пользоваться умеете? подебажьте

Comment: @VargSieg А вы сами проверяете, включен GPS, или нет?

Comment: Да точно у него есть ещё методы которые отвечают за отключение можете в ответ поставить, спасибо что на мысль навели)

Comment: "@VargSieg, я не знаю, что ставить в ответ, т. к. я не понял, что именно вам помогло, и тем более не понял, в чем была проблема.

Comment: Проблема была в том что данное 00,0000 значение  надо было с начала присвоить в отдельных методах переменным dataGPS1 и dataGPS1, а затем вызвать эти методы в методе отвечающим за отключение провайдера. И с вашей подачи мне это стало ясно.

Answer (score 4):

Поправьте функцию `formatLocation1()` и `formatLocation2()`

```
if (location == null)                         
    return "00.0000";
```

Из `showLocation()` уберите проверку на `null`

Comment: полагаю и `formatLocation2` тоже самое

Comment: Да, логично, поправил ответ)